# Why is the status bar sliding back of 20 points my image when I hide it?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

There appears to be a bug when `UIImagePickerController` gets called. The status bar shows up even it shouldn't.

To workaround that am using subclassing it:

```
class MyImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden() -> UIViewController? {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

and I use this code show up the Photo Library:

```
let picker = MyImagePickerController()

    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)
    picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
```

However, the status bar gets hidden but **it slides an image connected to the view via a constraint down of about 20 points.** How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this for my case by taking control of the nav bar in the imagePickerController. This *may* work for you, but it will depend on the precise context of your problem (i.e. state of view hierarchy before imagePicker is shown).

As with my [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28236054/1375695), you subclass UIImagePickerController. This is in turn a subclass of UINavigationController, so you can get at it's navbar.

```
class WNImagePickerControllerSwift: UIImagePickerController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.setNavBar()
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        self.setNavBar()
        return true
    }

    override func childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden() -> UIViewController? {
        return nil;
    }

    func setNavBar() -> Void {
        self.setNavBar(65)
    }


    func setNavBar(height: CGFloat) -> Void {
        var frame = self.navigationBar.frame;
        frame.size.height = height;
        self.navigationBar.frame = frame;
    }

}
```

`setNavBar` has to be called in precisely those two places - once before the animation transition when `prefersStatusBarHidden` is invoked, and once again after the transition. It won't work if you call it directly in `viewWillAppear`.

Anyway it's worth a try, playing around with that magic number 65 to suit the navbar height that you are after.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this 20 offset while editing image.  It seems like a bug to me as well.

The only thing that works for me is that in `info.list`, set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES`. Check if you have this set.

Then if you want to modify status bar in some of the viewcontrollers, go to every view controller needed to change it.